# Is it possible to compose shaders in sequence?

Tags: iphone, glsl

Is it possible to compose several fragment shaders in sequence under GLSL ES? I want to use two shaders S1 and S2 where S2 uses several fragments output by S1. For example, I'd like to apply two convolutions in sequence, in which case the second convolution needs access to the output of the first convolution at a bunch of pixel locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however this requires the use of one of two techniques.
The first an easiest is called multi-pass rendering.
In it you render the results of S1 to a texture then render S2 reading from the texture that holds the results of S1. However this is a bit inefficient as it removes some of the parallelism that is possible with a GPU. So it is often recommended that you use something called pipeling. This is a bit more complicated.

1. Create 2*N number of textures where N is the number of shaders. This is so that each shader can have both a read and a write texture.
2. Render every shader at once, reading from the read texture for the shader before it, and write to write texture.
3. At the end of each frame, swap the read and write textures.

This results in multiple iterations being computed at the same time. However each iteration is finished after N iterations.

Comment: Nice! I understand both approaches but why is the latter faster than the former? In the pipelining approach, isn't it the case that each shader operation with take time equal to the cost of all operations being performed at that node, whereas in multi-pass rendering the cost will be just the cost for one operation. Is it because there are overheads that prevent N executions of multi-pass rendering being as fast as one iteration of pipelining?

Comment: @AlexFlint GPU's often have fairly deep pipelines and generally can begin rendering other things before they are done rendering the pixels. Rendering reading from a texture that was just being rendered to can cause the graphics pipeline to stall until the rendering finishes on that texture. For example, on the iPhone, the vertices are processed in one frame and the fragments in the next. So using the first technique would make it require the equivalent of 3 frames of rendering which reduces the max FPS to 30 in this case. This is the same reason that things like glReadPixels are slow.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks very much for taking the time to explain - really helpful!

Comment: Do you by chance know of any code examples for this pipelining technique online? I've found a variety of GLSL pipelining examples but something specific to iOS would be super helpful because of the use of framebuffer objects etc.

Comment: I couldn't find any, but it is trivial to implement if you understand how to make a pipeline. I would recommend reading up on it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28software%29, as it can be a useful design pattern in general.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The main problem on GLSL ES (I'm working with iOS) is that each shader can only produce one output - i.e. there is just one gl_FragColor in contrast to the array gl_FragColor[i] under full GLSL. So far I haven't found a way to perform two parts of a computation in a single shader given this limitation.

Comment: @AlexFlit, you don't do the operation in one shader, you use multiple shaders across several draw calls. Also there is many tricks you can do as far as encoding goes. If you use an RGBA16F texture format (TEXTURE_HALF_FLOAT) you have 64 bits to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your continued patience. With only one output target under GLSL ES 2.0, won't this require N changes of output buffer per frame with glFramebufferTexture? Won't that ruin parallelism just as much as multi-pass rendering? I suppose with buffers with greater depth one could pack multiple buffers into a single GL buffer?

Comment: I know I'm *very* late to this party, but this might help you: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html